# Can I get the path of the PHP file originally called within an included file?

Tags: php, path

Let's say we have `index.php` and it is stored in `/home/user/public/www` and `index.php` calls the class `Foo->bar()` from the file `inc/app/Foo.class.php`.

I'd like the bar function in the `Foo` class to get a hold of the path `/home/user/public/www` in this instance — I don't want to use a global variable, pass a variable, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wouldn't this get you the directory of the running script more easily?

```
$dir=dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])
```

Comment: Good call Paul.  This will work most of the time.  It is possible, though, that you could have something that includes index.php.  For example, special.php includes index.php which includes inc/app/Foo.class.php.  This is rare, but possible.

Comment: Huh, I thought that didn't work if you called the script from the command line, but it does!

Answer (score 15):

You can use [debug_backtrace](https://www.php.net/debug_backtrace) to look at the calling path and get the file calling this function.

A short example:

```
class Foo {
  function bar() {    
   $trace = debug_backtrace();
   echo "calling file was ".$trace[0]['file']."\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`getcwd()` gets the current working directory

It can be changed for a variety of reasons by 3rd party modules, includes or even your own code by issuing a `chdir()`.

`debug_backtrace()` as Devon suggested is the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. getcwd().

Comment: Be aware that any call to chdir() will change the working directory, though.