# How to make a function keep the original URL without defining it

Tags: php, function, include

I have two files.

> file1.php

and

> /gallery/file2.php

**file1.php** has the function `showUrl();` which prints the current URL.
**file2.php** includes **file1.php**
If the function is executed in **file2.php** it will print the directory of the **file2.php**

How do I print the URL of the **file1.php** in **file2.php** with the function located in **file1.php** without defining it because the URL can change and can't be defined?

Comment: could you give an exemple of usage inside your files ? by "url" ou mean "path" ?

Comment: don't you know the url already because you can include it?

Comment: I get the path of the file2.php ,  but i need path of file1.php

Comment: In other words i want my function to keepthe path from file1.php

Comment: I know, you already said that. But if you have the path of file2 and you are able to include file1 then you should be able to combine the two and create the path of file1. You can find other answers to a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139794/can-i-get-the-path-of-the-php-file-originally-called-within-an-included-file

Answer (score 0):

try this:

file1.php

```
echo __FILE__;
```

file2.php

```
echo __FILE__;
include "../../file1.php" //or other path where your file1.php is located
```