# Is there some way to "figure out the application base dir" other than this?

Tags: php

I've made a PHP framework. To start it, you do:

```
require 'framework.php';
framework_start(__DIR__);
```

I'm trying to eliminate the `__DIR__` part, if at all possible. It's telling the framework what the "base dir" for the application is. I can't think of any way to determine the "`__DIR__`" for the file that calls `framework_start()`, from within `framework_start()`.

I can't help but feel annoyed that it can't just be:

```
require 'framework.php';
framework_start();
```

... and then `framework_start();` somehow figures out the `__DIR__` value on its own. But if I just reference `__DIR__` from the PHP file that contains `framework_start()`, it will obviously return the wrong dir path.

Is this possible at all? If so, how?

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393145/get-filename-of-file-which-ran-php-include

Comment: Not really... I see no solution on that page? But this, on the other hand, seems to actually solve it (but I'm not sure yet): https://stackoverflow.com/a/5670742/11555230

Comment: I was thinking about this `pathinfo(debug_backtrace()[0]['file'])['dirname']`

Comment: Does `framework.php` contain `framework_start()`?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, it seems like there should be a way... If there is you could even put the framework_start() call in the framework.php file, so all you'd need is the require.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139794/can-i-get-the-path-of-the-php-file-originally-called-within-an-included-file says you can use `$dir=dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])`...

Comment: What I linked to 7 minutes ago does NOT work! It screwed up my whole system because I was too happy and careless over finding the "solution"...

Comment: @Stevish That is only the top-most script and only if that variable is set. OP is asking for the direct parent file.

Comment: kerbholz: Yes. Stevish: That will only work in WWW mode, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: This is an excellent question. I'm going to sleep on it, but if I don't find the answer I'll be interested to find out if someone else does.

Comment: Hm, are you sure `__DIR__` would  _obviously return the wrong dir path_ when called from within `framework_start()`? Have you tried that? Since `framework.php` seems to be in the same folder as the file including it.

Comment: What? No. They are in completely different dirs. That's the whole point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following. Define a constant at the top of `framework.php` file to be used in your framework instead of `__DIR__`:

```
$trace = debug_backtrace(false);
$levelsToGoUp = 0; // set to 1 if called from within the function 
if (array_key_exists($levelsToGoUp, $trace)) {
    define('PARENTFILE', dirname($trace[$levelsToGoUp]['file']));
} else {
    define('PARENTFILE', __DIR__);
}
```

If you called `debug_backtrace()` inside the function `framework_start()` you would need to look at the entry with key 1 in the array (the first is the function itself), which I would recommend.

Comment: Although a bit confusing, this really helped me. I consider it the solution, even though (at least in my framework) also let the user (meaning me, for different projects) explicitly set the application base dir path, since it's not *always* the same as the file that "kickstarts" it. For example, I sometimes have the kickstart file in a subdir to the application dir, and for those situations, I send: __DIR__ . '/..' as an argument, and then it picks that instead of automatically determining it. However, now, with the help of your code snippet (which hopefully is stable), it normally requires no

Comment: argument. Thanks. (This stupid, over-engineered site has an ultra-low char limit for comments...)